# Stack multiple rows in one using VBA in microsoft excel

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I'm very new in this world of programming. I started with `VBA` 2 days ago and already encountered obstacle. My goal is to copy multiple columns (each from separate sheet) to one **`Database`** sheet (or Sheet2 as its referred in code). My code **`works`** but excel reports me error when I leave empty any of those columns. Any help or explanation would be very appreciated.

Code:

```
Sub prepravljeno()

    Sheet1.Activate
        Sheet1.Range(Range("C3"), Range("C3").End(xlDown)).Copy

    Sheet2.Activate
        Sheet2.Range(Range("C4"), Range("C4").End(xlDown)).PasteSpecial

    Sheet7.Activate
        Sheet7.Range(Range("C3"), Range("C3").End(xlDown)).Copy

    Sheet2.Activate
        Sheet2.Range("C4" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial

    Sheet6.Activate
        Sheet6.Range(Range("C3"), Range("C3").End(xlDown)).Copy

    Sheet2.Activate
        Sheet2.Range("C4" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial

    Sheet5.Activate
        Sheet5.Range(Range("C3"), Range("C3").End(xlDown)).Copy

    Sheet2.Activate
        Sheet2.Range("C4" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial

    Sheet4.Activate
        Sheet4.Range(Range("C3"), Range("C3").End(xlDown)).Copy

    Sheet2.Activate
        Sheet2.Range("C4" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial


        MsgBox "Podaci iz kolone 'Naziv aktivnosti' kopirani u list 'Baza aktivnosti'"
End Sub
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You dont need `.Activate` .  Have you defined `Dim Sheet1 as Worksheet` , `Set Sheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")` etc. ?

Comment: Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Comment: I did not define Sheet1 as worksheet, could you help me with that?

Comment: Sheet1 is a worksheet object. It doesn't need to be defined in your `Sub`. Your error is probably happening due to you trying to paste to what evaluates to `Range(C31048576)` which is beyond the maximum limit of the sheet. You need to fix where the paste destination is instead of `Range("C3" & Rows.Count)`

Comment: Also get rid of the `.Activate`

Comment: Thanks Tom, could you please rewrite that part of code?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub prepravljeno()

    With Sheet2
        Sheet1.Range(Range("C3"), Range("C3").End(xlDown)).Copy
        .Range(Range("C4"), Range("C4").End(xlDown)).PasteSpecial
        Sheet7.Range(Range("C3"), Range("C3").End(xlDown)).Copy
        .Range("C" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial
        Sheet6.Range(Range("C3"), Range("C3").End(xlDown)).Copy
        .Range("C" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial
        Sheet5.Range(Range("C3"), Range("C3").End(xlDown)).Copy
        .Range("C" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial
        Sheet4.Range(Range("C3"), Range("C3").End(xlDown)).Copy
        .Range("C" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial
    End With

    MsgBox "Podaci iz kolone 'Naziv aktivnosti' kopirani u list 'Baza aktivnosti'"
End Sub
```

Comment: It still gives me the same error. Here is the file, maybe that can help https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B62hLxLAY_-7M2NCeUx1ZHphekE